# Lowercase script in sql files

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, notepad++

I have to update all words from some sql files from uppercase to lowercase except the values, which are quoted words.

The simplest solution would be a regex and I tried to create one, but since I do not have much experience, its getting to difficult

```
search: ([\w]+?)('[\s\S]+?') 
replace: $1\L$2
```

so far I did this. 
There is a strange behavior happening here, in that some lines are duplicated.

the regex has to convert sql statements like this:

```
Insert into AAAA (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4) values (1, 'BBB', null, 'AAA');
```

to this:

```
insert into aaaa (field1, field2, field3, field4) values (1, 'BBB', null, 'AAA');
```

Comment: That is not clear. If you you say all the words, why `Insert` is still capitalized?

Comment: my bad, you are right, I fixed it

Comment: Can you show us more code so that the problem is clear?

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which tool, SublimeText2?

Comment: idea, because I want to apply this regex on a directory, there are many files that need to be updated

Comment: Sorry, I can only suggest a solution for Notepad++. There is an option to find and replace in files, and directories, and subdirectories, BTW.

Comment: if it works just give it to me, I will find a way to make it work with notepad as well

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ok, very good, does not really matter the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++, you may also find and replace text in multiple files in folders and even subfolders. Press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>, click *Find In Files*, fill out the necessary fields, and click *Replace in Files*.

You may match all `'...'` substrings and match and capture all the word character chunks, and then check what group matched. If Group 1 matched, turn it to lowercase, else, paste back as is.

*Find What*:      `'[^']+'|(\w+)`
*Replace With*: `(?{1}\L$1:$0)`

**Regex details**:

- `'[^']+'` - match `'`, then 1+ chars other than `'` and again a `'`
- `|` - or
- `(\w+)` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more word chars

**Replacement pattern details**:

- `(?{1}` - if Group 1 matched...

  - `\L$1` - return the Group 1 value in lower case
  - `:` - else...
  - `$0` - return the whole match (the `'...'` substring)
- `)` - end of the conditional replacement pattern.

[image]